# XML to XLS Transformation through XSLT

Tags: xslt

How to retraverse an xml while converting into .xls file through XSLT?

I have the request xml as:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<report>
<header>
<request_id>121</request_id><content_provider>ews</content_provider><report_date>2013-09-26</report_date>
</header>

<policy_detail><client_name>MR JOHN PHILIP GRACE</client_name><date_of_birth>1954-04-21</date_of_birth><policy_number>0081467839</policy_number><clawback>518.67</clawback><date_policy_inception>1992-08-07</date_policy_inception>106085</frn><master_agent_number>1212190</master_agent_number><agent_number>6354773</agent_number><clawback_date>      </clawback_date>
</policy_detail>

<policy_detail><client_name>MISS LISA PORTER</client_name><date_of_birth>1970-05-18</date_of_birth><policy_number>0082625310</policy_number><clawback>463.72</clawback><date_policy_inception>1994-05-17</date_policy_inception><frn>106085</frn><master_agent_number>1212190</master_agent_number><agent_number>6366264</agent_number><clawback_date>      </clawback_date>
</policy_detail>

<policy_detail><client_name>MRS ELAINE LOCKYER</client_name><date_of_birth>1957-09-07</date_of_birth><policy_number>0108791948</policy_number><clawback>64.98</clawback><date_policy_inception>2004-07-01</date_policy_inception><frn>106085</frn><master_agent_number>2178267</master_agent_number><agent_number>1212189</agent_number><clawback_date>      </clawback_date>
</policy_detail>

<policy_detail><client_name>MR DEMETRIOUS PAPI</client_name><date_of_birth>1957-10-25</date_of_birth><policy_number>0019751627
</policy_number><clawback>427.71</clawback><date_policy_inception>1992-05-07</date_policy_inception><frn>106085</frn><master_agent_number>2001188</master_agent_number><agent_number>2009744</agent_number><clawback_date>      </clawback_date>
</policy_detail>

<summary><policy_count>4</policy_count><clawback_total>1475.08</clawback_total>
</summary>
</report>
```

The processing XSL is:--

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-template/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="policy_detail">
<xsl:value-of select="client_name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Below this, I have to insert code of calculating total clawback on the basis of a particular master_agent_no i.e. 1212190.

Comment: It might help if you explain where you're stuck, as well as what error messages you're getting, as well as what output you expect to get from this.

Comment: XML to XSLT doesn't make much sense -- do you mean XML to Excel (XLS)?

Comment: yeah sure I mean the same.

Comment: @jmort253:-- Thanks for your interest. I want the total clawback corresponding to a particular master agent should be displayed at the bottom of the page after traversing all the policy details. So I think it requires the traversal of all the nodes again. Or is there any other idea ......... please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add code that outputs

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//policy_detail[agent_number='1212190']/clawback)"/>
```

at the appropriate point in your stylesheet code.

Comment: Thanks.......... But I want the total clawback should be displayed at the bottom of the page after traversing all the policy details. So I think it requires the traversal of all the nodes again.

Comment: Thanks.......... But I want the total clawback should be displayed at the bottom of the page after traversing all the policy details. So I think it requires the traversal of all the nodes again. Also above solution will work when <xsl:template match="report"> not <xsl:template match="policy_detail"> and report is the parent node for node policy_detail and I think it is pretty much defficult to back traverse to parent node from child node.

Comment: Yes, it requires the traversal of all the nodes again. That's the XSLT way. And the code I gave you works fine in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: But how to retraverse the nodes?

Comment: I think you need to do some reading. Go through some worked examples.